# lateinit property binding has not been initialized / Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I am having an issue with binding even I have it initialized, but it does not recognize it. I have both dataBinding & viewBinding enabled.

**Here is my fragment of the code**

```
class QuizQuestionActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityQuizQuestionBinding
private var mCurrentPosition: Int = 1 // Default and the first question position
private var mQuestionsList: ArrayList<Question>? = null
private var mSelectedOptionPosition: Int = 0
private var mCorrectAnswers: Int = 0

// TODO (STEP 3: Create a variable for getting the name from intent.)
// START
private var mUserName: String? = null
// END

/**
 * This function is auto created by Android when the Activity Class is created.
 */
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //This call the parent constructor
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityQuizQuestionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    // This is used to align the xml view to this class
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_question)

    // TODO (STEP 4: Get the NAME from intent and assign it the variable.)
    // START
    mUserName = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.USER_NAME)
    // END

    mQuestionsList = Constants.getQuestions()

    setQuestion()

    binding.tvOptionOne.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.tvOptionTwo.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.tvOptionThree.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.tvOptionFour.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```

**Snippet of my gradle file**

```
    buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
    viewBinding = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Insted of `setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_question)` use `setContentView(binding.root)`

Comment: I have tried it before but still i get the same error @anshul

Comment: Why both databinding and viewBinding enabled ?

Comment: using both databinding and viewbinding on same layout file is creating ambiguity and hence throwing a error

Comment: Yes @Anshul , I have also thought about it, you mean in the gradle file right?

Comment: that can be a reason , why use both?

Comment: Because i have binding.btnSubmit.text - which consist '.text', so if i delete view binding it marks as an error. I was doing it according tutorial, but it was made without binding so the android studio asked to make with binding